# Mostrar diferentes filas en la misma consulta

Tags: mysql

Hola chicos tengo un problema con una consulta en mysql, quizás es super sencilla pero necesito un empujón para poder sacarla.

Es una tabla de registraciones de estudiantes en el cual, cada estudiante tiene diferentes status como "Registrado", "Cancelado", "Pendiente", "En Proceso".

Lo que quiero hacer que en la misma consulta me muestre una fila de cuantos hay en status registrados, otra fila cuantos hay en cancelado y así.

[image: Asi se deberia ver la tabla que estoy populando]

[image: Asi esta disenada la tabla la columna registration es la de estatus]

Comment: Debes poner lo que has intentado hasta ahora y en qué te ha fallado para poder ayudar

Comment: select COUNT(registration) 
from students_courses
where id_course = 'C4-1' and registration = 'Registered'

Comment: Con esa consulta me arroja un count de todos los que estan con status registrados, pero necesito mostrar en la misma consulta un count con los diferentes status. muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría hacerlo vertical en lugar de horizantal como especificas pero para hacerlo horizontal la forma más directa con mysql es utilizando sub-querys.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablaX WHERE status ='Registrado') AS Registrado, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablaX WHERE status ='Cancelado') as Cancelado, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablaX WHERE status ='Pendiente') as Pendiente, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablaX WHERE status ='En Proceso') as "En Proceso"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por eso, me sirvio muchisimo